# Get All documents that contains a particular attribute in Alfresco using dotcmis

Tags: .net, alfresco, cmis, dotcmis

Today i was looking for a good way for get all documents that contains a particular attribute in alfresco using dotcmis.

I was thinking in:

- Use Ephesoft (http://www.ephesoft.com/) to capture documents.
- Connect Ephesoft with Alfresco using cmis integration.
- Configure document properties to match with a alfresco model (metadata document)
- Develop a module in my webApplication (asp.net) to search all document with a particular property(metadata); using dotcmis (http://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/dotcmis.html)

I finded:

- How create a session.
- How list tree folder

except... How verify every document if have setted a particular property (metadata)?

Do you know how do it?

---

Thanks pablochan!
In this moment, i have:

```
public ISession Connect(string user, string password, string servicesUrl, string repositoryId)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> parameter = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        parameter.Add(DotCMIS.SessionParameter.User, user);
        parameter.Add(DotCMIS.SessionParameter.Password, password);
        parameter.Add(DotCMIS.SessionParameter.BindingType, DotCMIS.BindingType.WebServices);
        parameter.Add(DotCMIS.SessionParameter.WebServicesAclService, (servicesUrl + "ACLService?wsdl").ToString());
        parameter.Add(DotCMIS.SessionParameter.WebServicesDiscoveryService, (servicesUrl + "DiscoveryService?wsdl").ToString());
        parameter.Add(DotCMIS.SessionParameter.WebServicesMultifilingService, (servicesUrl + "MultiFilingService?wsdl").ToString());
        parameter.Add(DotCMIS.SessionParameter.WebServicesNavigationService, (servicesUrl + "NavigationService?wsdl").ToString());
        parameter.Add(DotCMIS.SessionParameter.WebServicesObjectService, (servicesUrl + "ObjectService?wsdl").ToString());
        parameter.Add(DotCMIS.SessionParameter.WebServicesPolicyService, (servicesUrl + "PolicyService?wsdl").ToString());
        parameter.Add(DotCMIS.SessionParameter.WebServicesRelationshipService, (servicesUrl + "RelationshipService?wsdl").ToString());
        parameter.Add(DotCMIS.SessionParameter.WebServicesRepositoryService, (servicesUrl + "RepositoryService?wsdl").ToString());
        parameter.Add(DotCMIS.SessionParameter.WebServicesVersioningService, (servicesUrl + "VersioningService?wsdl").ToString());
        parameter.Add(DotCMIS.SessionParameter.RepositoryId, (repositoryId));

        ISessionFactory factory = DotCMIS.Client.Impl.SessionFactory.NewInstance();
        return factory.CreateSession(parameter);
    }

    public List<CMISIntegrationResponse> GetFiles(CMISIntegrationRequest request)
    {
        List<CMISIntegrationResponse> cmisIntegrationResponseList = new List<CMISIntegrationResponse>();

        ISession session = Connect(request.UserName, request.Password, request.ServicesUrl, request.RepositoryId);

        IItemEnumerable<IQueryResult> result = session.Query(@"SELECT
                                                               cmis:name, cmis:objectId, cmis:baseTypeId, cmis:objectTypeId, cmis:createdBy,
                                                               cmis:lastModifiedBy, cmis:lastModificationDate,cmis:contentStreamMimeType,
                                                               cmis:contentStreamFileName,cmis:contentStreamId,cmis:contentStreamLength
                                                               FROM cmis:document
                                                               ORDER BY
                                                               cmis:name, cmis:createdBy", false);

        foreach(QueryResult item in result) 
        {
            if (item.AllowableActions.Actions.Contains(DotCMIS.Actions.CanGetContentStream))
            {
                foreach (DotCMIS.Data.IPropertyData property in item.Properties)
                {

                    /*AccountNumber will be a property/metadata of any document
                      In this point i can not see any property/metadata called  "AccountNumber"
                     */

                    if (property.DisplayName.Equals("AccountNumber"))
                    {
                        CMISIntegrationResponse response = new CMISIntegrationResponse();
                        response.Name = item.GetPropertyValueByQueryName("cmis:name").ToString();
                        response.ObjectId = item.GetPropertyValueByQueryName("cmis:objectId").ToString();
                        response.BaseTypeId = item.GetPropertyValueByQueryName("cmis:baseTypeId").ToString();
                        response.ObjectTypeId = item.GetPropertyValueByQueryName("cmis:objectTypeId").ToString();
                        response.CreatedBy = item.GetPropertyValueByQueryName("cmis:createdBy").ToString();
                        response.LastModifiedBy = item.GetPropertyValueByQueryName("cmis:lastModifiedBy").ToString();
                        response.LastModificationDate = item.GetPropertyValueByQueryName("cmis:lastModificationDate").ToString();
                        response.ContentStreamMimeType = item.GetPropertyValueByQueryName("cmis:contentStreamMimeType").ToString();
                        response.ContentStreamFileName = item.GetPropertyValueByQueryName("cmis:contentStreamFileName").ToString();
                        response.ContentStreamId = item.GetPropertyValueByQueryName("cmis:contentStreamId").ToString();
                        response.ContentStreamLength = item.GetPropertyValueByQueryName("cmis:contentStreamLength").ToString();

                        cmisIntegrationResponseList.Add(response);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        session.Clear();
        return cmisIntegrationResponseList;
    }
```

Where can i see a list of the virtual tables and their columns of CMIS Alfresco?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can send a CMIS query to Alfresco. I recommend [reading about CMIS Query Language first](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS_Query_Language). After that [read the dotCMIS guide](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/guide.html).

Let's say that you have a type or aspect defined with your field e.g. my:aspect and my:field.

The query could look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my:aspect WHERE my:field = "some value"
```

The code would be:

```
session.Query("SELECT * FROM my:aspect WHERE my:field = 'some value'", false);
```

EDIT:

Ok, I read your code and there is one more thing I didn't mention. The reason you're not seeing your field (account number) is because the query result contains only the fields defined for the queried type/aspect (in this case cmis:object). If you want to query against "AccountNumber" you need to know the type/aspect it's defined in.

Let's say that "AccountNumber" is defined in the type "custom:myType". The query would look like this:

```
SELECT * from custom:myType
```

The result will contain "AccountNumber".

If the field is defined in an aspect, you can do a query with a JOIN: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS#Aspect_Query

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Where can i see a list of the virtual tables and their columns of CMIS
>   Alfresco?

The best way to do this is to download the OpenCMIS Workbench from Apache Chemistry. Start it up, connect to Alfresco, then click Types. The Workbench will then display a hierarchical list of the types that the repository knows about.

If you then click on a specific type you are interested in the Workbench will display the properties of that type. If you scroll over you'll see a "queryable" column. If that column is true you can write queries that test that property's value. Use the property's "Query Name" in your query.